# jQuery addClass() / removeClass() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
    <li class="selected"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

That is my html. And the selectors I am using right now are:

```
    $("ul li:eq(0)").removeClass('selected');
    $("ul li:eq(1)").addClass('selected');
```

Problem is that I can not add or remove the 'selected' class from these elements.
The html and jquery are both pretty straight-forward and as many examples as I could find did everything the same way, including official jQuery docs. (The script is loaded before the body tag, if it matters)

Why can't I remove and add the classes like this?

The entire html page [here](http://pastebin.com/iMmDVgCz)

Comment: You can, the problem must be elsewhere such as where this script is located, when it runs, how jQuery is included, etc.

Comment: check your browser console

Comment: I tried running the script from a file, which was included right before the </body> tag. I also tried running the code from a <script> tag right in the html.(also located right before the body tag)I use googles cdn for jquery, but everything else uses jquery also and is added before this script and everything else works...)

Comment: can you publish the entire page for us to see?

Comment: added link to the whole php script

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). Then you notice that you have a syntax error. You are missing the closing `);` for the event handler binding, which will prevent the whole code block from executing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is a syntax error in the rest of the OP's code.

Answer (score 6):

probably because you forgot to add `$(document).ready()` ,also make sure you added the jquery.min.js file

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("ul li:eq(0)").removeClass('selected');
    $("ul li:eq(1)").addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Does not help me, but thanx for the reminder. I added the link to my whole code.

Comment: Under what action you want to change your class?

Answer (score 2):

The code looks correct, the problem must be elsewhere. How to debug this:

1. Look at how many elements the selector matches:

   ```
   console.log($("ul li:eq(1)").length);
   ```

   If you see 0, then the selector didn't match anything.
2. Which element did match?

   ```
   console.log($("ul li:eq(1)")[0]);
   ```

   Most browsers allow to examine the element in the console.

A typical problem is that your code is executed before the elements exist. In the simple case, you just need to run your code after the DOM is ready:

```
$(function () {
    ...DOM is now ready...
});
```

But sometimes, other scripts will create elements. If that's the case for you, you'll need to tell us which frameworks and scripts you use to build / manipulate the DOM.

Related:

- [Debugging your selectors in jQuery](http://www.getoffmalawn.com/blog/debugging-your-selectors-in-jquery)

Comment: $(document).ready( function () {console.log('This is text');}); This does not even log in the console, which is unexplainable...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li:eq(0)").removeClass('selected');
$("ul li:eq(1)").addClass('selected');
```

works for me (http://jsfiddle.net/orlando/rhtqA/)

but yeah you need to wait till DOM is ready to do stuff with jquery

```
$(function () {
    $("ul li:eq(0)").removeClass('selected');
    $("ul li:eq(1)").addClass('selected');
});
```